# Adding multiple new values to MBTILES layer using `tile-join`

Tags: mapbox, mbtiles, tippecanoe

Using the [tile-join](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe#tile-join) function of tippecanoe, I have a MBTILES file with one point, and a CSV with one value to add to that point. This is what the CSV looks like:
[image]
I am able to edit the MBTILES layer by using the key to add the TIMESTAMP using the CSV file, although it removes the key value (OBJECT_ID) from the MBTILES file when it adds the TIMESTAMP in. I believe it's simply replacing one value with the other. Here's what I'm using in the command line: 
`tile-join -o updated_objects.mbtiles -x OBJECT_ID -c changes.csv objects.mbtiles`

I've tried variations to this, such as removing the `-x`, although I haven't been able to keep the existing OBJECT_ID and the TIMESTAMP in the updated file.

Is there a way to add one or multiple values into an MBTILES file while still keeping the existing data?